# How to solve error Identifier has already been declared?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to solve this error? `Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'role' has already been declared` in PHP? I have no idea how to solve this issue.

**PHP**

```
<?php session_start(); 

if ($_SESSION['user_privilege'] == "Admin"){
    echo "<script>
       let role = 'Admin';
    </script>";
  } else {
   echo "<script>
       let role = 'User';
    </script>";
  }

?>
```

**JS**

```
var test = "";
if (role != "Admin"){
    test = "anything";
}
```

Comment: What is the actual HTML generated by the PHP? (Use "View Source", which shows the actual HTML, not "inspect element", which shows the browser's _interpretation_ of the HTML, silently correcting errors.)

Comment: That's a JavaScript error, not a PHP error, and [tag:jquery] doesn't seem to be involved at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your script as follows:

```
<?php session_start(); 

if ($_SESSION['user_privilege'] == "Admin") {
   echo "<script>
       var role = 'Admin';
    </script>";
} else {
   echo "<script>
       var role = 'User';
    </script>";
} ?>
```